# Where can i find the sapient metal?

Tags: battleheart-legacy

I quickly clicked through an interface - it sounded like the weapons merchant is capped (his tools are not good enough), and there is a quest somewhere in the "northwest mountains" to unlock higher level weapons.

i can't seem to find this quest, though. Where is it/where do i go to find him metal for his tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metal is not "Sapient Metal" - it's "Living Metal". It's available on the level 21 boss in the north west corner of the map, and there are a few glitches around it (eg, it may not show up in your inventory/you might not get a message saying you've looted it).

For complete details, check out the level 20/21 portions of [this walkthrough](http://www.appunwrapper.com/2014/06/03/battleheart-legacy-world-map-npc-locations-and-quests-by-level/).

Comment: When you beat the boss for the first time, an achievement banner pops that hides an in-game notification. This notification would tell you that you received the Living Metal, so beating this boss for the first time can be confusing. If you had the quest to retrieve Living Metal and you killed the boss, you can safely return to the smith to buy new stuff.  :)